# How can i run the project which have folders like conf,css,html,js,jsp and WEB-INF?

Tags: java, web-deployment, setup-deployment

I have one java web project folder and it contains folders like `/conf`, `/css`, `/html`, `/js`, `/jsp` and `/WEB-INF`.

`/conf` folder contains `vestweb.cfg`, `*.css`, `*.html`, `*.js`, `*.jsp` files.
`/WEB-INF` has `/src` folder and contains java source files(not able to find project to import.).
I could not find any root files(.war) in those folders.

How can I configure this folders to run the application?

Comment: search for tomcat/jetty/resin.. on net and see how you deploy these together and run it.

Comment: You probably need to deploy to a web server

Comment: @CocoNess  The OP has only source files. A deployment doesn't work.

Comment: Your problem is that you dont know about java web projet, so you have to search how to run one java web projet, if you projet is only the source code (*.java) you have to compile it, if is already compile you have to run it in some java ee wrapper like tomcat/jetty... you can find a lots of this information in the web. And normally you have the instruction of what to do with the projet, so search README or something like that in the projet or in the page where did you found the projet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need to do is package the folder structure into a deployable package (exploded or compressed).

1. Compile the java source from "WEB-INF/src" folder and copy the class files to "WEB-INF/classes" folder
2. You can rename the root folder as "[YOUR_PROJECT].war" or you can compress it to a .WAR file
3. Deploy the package into any web-application server
4. Access your files from browser

Comment: Thanks for quick replay Adheep. One more thing i could not find any root file in that folders. If so how can i do the same.

Comment: My bad, "root" meaning the higher level folder in which the CSS, JS, and JSP files are located.

You can select all these files and package as War also!